# Android ScrollView - 1st tap is not registered

Tags: android

I have created an android app with a dynamic scrolling interface.  When a user scrolls the first tap is not registered.

Just a guess, but it seems like the first tap is considering the tap to stop the scrolling, even if the user already reached the bottom of the scrollview.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some code please. I am guessing you are overriding onTouch event of the ScrollView and trying to implement something custom. What is your desired functionality and what seems to be the problem?